# Pandas DataFrame to dict

Tags: python, pandas

Есть такой DataFrame:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=["ind1","ind2"])
df.name = 'dfname'
df

    col1    col2
ind1   1    3
ind2   2    4
```

Как наиболее просто и элегантно получить:

```
out = { 
    'dfname_ind1_col1' : '1',
    'dfname_ind1_col2' : '3',
    'dfname_ind2_col1' : '2',
    'dfname_ind2_col2' : '4'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
In [229]: df
Out[229]: 
      col1  col2
ind1     1     3
ind2     2     4

In [230]: df.name                                 
Out[230]: 'dfname'

In [231]: {'_'.join((df.name,) + k): v for k, v in df.stack().to_dict().items()}
Out[231]: 
{'dfname_ind1_col1': 1,
 'dfname_ind1_col2': 3,
 'dfname_ind2_col1': 2,
 'dfname_ind2_col2': 4}
```

```
In [16]: df.stack()
Out[16]: 
ind1  col1    1
      col2    3
ind2  col1    2
      col2    4
dtype: int64

In [17]: df.stack().to_dict() 
Out[17]: 
{('ind1', 'col1'): 1,
 ('ind1', 'col2'): 3,
 ('ind2', 'col1'): 2,
 ('ind2', 'col2'): 4}
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо.